# How to check if today and specific date is same using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to check if today and a specific date is same using moment.

```
const today = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(today) // "28/09/2021"
const expiry = moment(new Date('2021/09/28')).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(expiry) // "28/09/2021"
```

Now When I compare , I am getting false

```
console.log(moment(today).isSame(expiry)); // false

It also showing me this in fiddle,
"Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
```

Comment: `.format()` returns a string. `moment()` returns a Moment object. `today` and `expiry` are strings. Then you do `moment(today)`, which re-converts a string into a Moment object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare it directly by operator `==`

```js
const today = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(today) // "28/09/2021"
const expiry = moment(new Date('2021/09/28')).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(expiry) // "28/09/2021"

console.log(today == expiry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const today = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(today) // "28/09/2021"
const expiry = moment(new Date('2021/09/28')).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
console.log(expiry) // "28/09/2021"
```

It's because here, you're setting today and expiry to strings, eg "21/12/2021"
and then asking moment to come strings when it's expecting dates.

Also need to add the flag 'day' to `isSame`

Try this instead

```js
const today = moment(new Date());
console.log(today.format('DD/MM/YYYY')) // "28/09/2021"
const expiry = moment(new Date('2021/09/28'));
console.log(expiry.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

console.log(moment(today).isSame(expiry, 'day'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to convert your code into a snippet, including Moment

Comment: @JeremyThille looks good

Comment: Yep but it's not working. Today is Sept 28th 2021, the output should be `true`. It says `false`

Comment: Corrected it now